# Set DatePicker value from Javascript by parsing JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, razor, datepicker

I have a text input field in my .cshtml page which is a Date type field.

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="comments">ETA:</label>
     <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" id="MilestoneETAEdit" name="MilestoneETAEdit" type="date" value="">
</div>
```

This field nicely renders as a input field, with a calendar drop down at the right. I can select any date from the calendar manually. after selecting, the input field shows the date in `MM/dd/yyyy` format

But later in the page life cycle, I need to parse a JSON and set this field to the value which is coming from the jSON.

The date field is coming like this in JSON.

```
{
  "ETA":"/Date(1571855400000)/"
}
```

I tried to set the value of the input field by trying the following approaches:

```
$('#MilestoneETAEdit').val(result.ETA);
```

it does not work, I even tried to hard code the value. This does not work either:

```
$('#MilestoneETAEdit').val('09/18/2019');
```

How can I set the value in the input field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `/Date(` and `/` from the ETA value and convert that string to date using `new Date()` object. Now, input type date accept value in `yyyy-mm-dd` format, you need to convert date to desired format and set `val()` to input to see the date

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var result = {"ETA":"/Date(1571855400000)/"};
  var date = result.ETA.replace('/Date(','').replace(')','').replace('/','');
  console.log(date);
  var dateVal = new Date(parseInt(date)).toLocaleDateString();
  console.log(dateVal);
 dateVal = dateVal.substring(6,10) + "-" + dateVal.substring(0,2) + "-" + dateVal.substring(3,5);
  console.log(dateVal);
  $('#MilestoneETAEdit').val(dateVal);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="comments">ETA:</label>
     <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" id="MilestoneETAEdit" name="MilestoneETAEdit" type="date" value="">
</div>
```